# Can I return results from npm async parallel inside a function

Tags: node.js, async.js

I would like to return the results from the npm async in nodejs, it returns undefined when I call the function 'findRequestAgent'

```
findRequestAgent : (agentId) => {
   var queries = [];
   var datum;
   queries.push((callback) => {
    MovingAgent.findById(agentId,(err,doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error finding the moving agent");
            throw err;
        }

        callback(null, doc)
    })
   });

   queries.push((callback) => {
     SelfStander.findOne({ user_id: agentId}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error finding the self stander");
            throw err;                
        }

        callback(null, doc)
     })
   });

   queries.push((callback) =>{
     MovingCompany.findOne({custom_id: agentId}, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error finding the self stander");
            throw err;                
        }

        callback(null, doc);
     })
   });

   async.parallel(queries, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error perfoming async");
            throw err;                
        }
        datum = results;
       console.log(datum);
   });

   return datum;
}
```

What can I do so that when I call the above function 'findRequestAgent' it returns the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the Mongo queries return promises.

```
var queries = [];

queries.push(
  MovingAgent.findById(agentId,(err,doc) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log("There was an error finding the moving agent");
          throw err;
      }

      return (null, doc);
  })
);
```

...

```
return Promise.all(queries).then(
  (results) => results; //array of results
).catch(
  (err) => console.log(err);
)
```

No need for the async part

Comment: So because my function returns pending, does it mean I need to subscribe again? Because it is no longer returning undefined, but returns this :  Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Well you need to run the function like `findRequestAgent(agentId).then(
  (results) => console.log(results); // do something with the results here
)`

Comment: Like findRequestAgent(par).then(()=>{ do something})?

Comment: Well in that example it wouldn't do anything with the results. The arrow function needs to take an argument `(results) => {do something with "results"}`

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, asynchronous functions don't return values directly. You need to use another mechanism such as a callback, events, promises.

Without knowing more about your use case, it's hard to know what the right solution is. But you should definitely stop and make sure you understand how asynchronous functions work in JavaScript before continuing.

The easiest solution is to do what you need to do in side the callback passed to `.parallel()` but again, without knowing more, it can't be said for certain that that will work for your use case.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, and I tried returning the results from within the parallel(err,callback(){ return something;}) I was not successful, if that's what you meant

Comment: No, you cannot return a value from a callback. That's not how it works. You can emit an event, or resolve a promise, or any number of other possibilities, but you cannot return a value.

Comment: Trott, can you give me an example of how I would resolve this promise for a simple function that must return a value from a promise, well if you have the time of course

Comment: Looks like JellyKid tried to give an example in their answer. Check it out and upvote it if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you Trott, you have been helpful